# Determine if base64 encoded GIF is animated in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64, gif

I'm adding functionality to the file uploader that I created that has a built in image cropper. Currently, I disable cropping on gifs as sending the gif to the canvas and getting the base64 of it damages animated gifs. I was wondering if there was a way to determine from the base64 if a GIF is animated?

Comment: Find a function that converts the Base64 string to an ArrayBuffer/Uint8Array then this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11250140/246342

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, I had hoped I would have to do that. Isn't it potentially slow?

Comment: I would not have thought so, ultimately you will need to try it and see

Comment: @AlexK. Should do shouldn't I