# Make FilePond Image Transform plugin ignore (animated) GIFs

Tags: filepond

I'm using FilePond with an image editor, so I also load the Image Transform plugin.

However, when a user uploads a GIF file, I want the outputted image to remain a GIF file. Currently it's transformed to a PNG by the Image Transform plugin.

Is there a way to make FilePond disable the Image Transform plugin when a GIF file is uploaded, or somehow change the output mime-type?

Comment: Hi, are you using the latest version of the image transform plugin?

Comment: @Rik Yes, I'm using FilePondPluginImageTransform 3.5.2

Comment: Have you set an output format (`imageTransformOutputMimeType`)? You could also try setting `imageTransformOutputQualityMode` to 'optional'

Comment: @Rik no output format is specified. Setting `imageTransformOutputQualityMode` to 'optional' doesn't work either. It only works when I set `allowImageTransform` to false. Also tried to not configure Doka as the `imageEditEditor` that also didn't work.

Comment: Weird, I'll take a look tomorrow or at the beginning of next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install version `3.6.0` of the image transform plugin and use the function below to filter out animated GIF images.

Animated GIF filter code snippet from
[Is it possible to detect animated gif images client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326890/is-it-possible-to-detect-animated-gif-images-client-side)

```js
FilePond.create({
    imageTransformImageFilter: (file) => new Promise(resolve => {

        // no gif mimetype, do transform
        if (!/image\/gif/.test(file.type)) return resolve(true);

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {

            var arr = new Uint8Array(reader.result),
            i, len, length = arr.length, frames = 0;

            // make sure it's a gif (GIF8)
            if (arr[0] !== 0x47 || arr[1] !== 0x49 || 
                arr[2] !== 0x46 || arr[3] !== 0x38) {
                // it's not a gif, we can safely transform it
                resolve(true);
                return;
            }

            for (i=0, len = length - 9; i < len, frames < 2; ++i) {
                if (arr[i] === 0x00 && arr[i+1] === 0x21 &&
                    arr[i+2] === 0xF9 && arr[i+3] === 0x04 &&
                    arr[i+8] === 0x00 && 
                    (arr[i+9] === 0x2C || arr[i+9] === 0x21)) {
                    frames++;
                }
            }

            // if frame count > 1, it's animated, don't transform
            if (frames > 1) {
                return resolve(false);
            }

            // do transform
            resolve(true);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    })
});
```