# Can document.querySelector() Find All IMG Elements that Show an Animated GIF?

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-selectors, animated-gif

Assume that a browser is open, and a webpage finished loading, and that page contains many `IMG` Elements.

A few of these `IMG` Elements are Animated GIFs.

I would like to use DOM, to programmatically get only the Animated GIFs `IMG` Elements.

For a start, I can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll("img[src$='.gif']");
```

which will Find all `IMG` Elements that are GIF files.

But not all GIF files are Animated GIFs..
So how can I continue from here, to Filter for the ones that are Animated?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250140/8629960) might help

Comment: Not out of the box, so you have to use a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/animated-gif-detector

Comment: **Kirill Simonov:** Interesting. His function redownloads the image, in order to Binary inspect it. Could he simply get the Binary data from the Element object? (since the IMG elements already loaded)..

Comment: **Tokant:** Thank you, but I am on a Browser, not Node.js..